Arrangement of magnets to get high magnetic field at centre of circle
The objective is to create an arrangement of magnets (preferably in a circular array like a ring/ bangle) in such a way that the magnetic field at the centre of circular array is very high and at remaining points away from the center (both inside and outside the circular array), the magnetic field should be negligible (ideally zero). Is there any such arrangement of magnets possible that can partially or fully fulfill this objective? Can you explain how to achieve this in a cost-effective way?

Can you draw a sketch of what you want, showing the lines of flux going from the north pole(s) to the south pole(s)? (I suspect that you've forgotten that the flux has to return to the magnet somehow.) Some context would be helpful. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Looks, like you want magnetic field which points away from a certain area and is strongest in the middle of that area. If we think the magnetic field lines as water flow trajectories there should be a source of a water in the middle of your magnet array. The source only outputs, there's no input. Or as well we could say that you want magnetic field which geometrically is like the electric field of a positively charged piece of material.
Unfortunately such magnetic field doesn't exist before someone finds a way to make magnetic monopoles. Until it happens, there's no solution. All known technical methods to generate magnetic fields produce only fields which occur as closed loops.
If your real application actually doesn't need magnetic field which points outwards from the midpoint to every 3D space direction, but allows the field lines to return from some direction you may get an useful answer. To have a possibility to get it you should reveal something of your application.
